# Reset Controls for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I began using C# and WPF a few months ago and now I thought I'd try to learn some new techniques like using threading. So I have an app that I want to run all the time (using an infinity while loop) but show the dialog (main window) every minute. So I am doing this by using Threading and here is how i am doing this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    while (true)
    {
        callmyfunction()
         system.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

In my callmyfunction(), I am calling the dialog (which is the main WPF application) so it will show. Here's how i am doing it:

```
public void callmyfunction()
{
    this.ShowDialog();
}
```

I have a regular button and when you click on it, it should hide the main window. So my button function is like this:

```
private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
}
```

So what I am doing is, I am loading the main window normally and it has a button, when I click on that button, it should hide the main window and the window should sleep as per the milli-seconds I specified in thread.sleep and then it will wake up, then again the dialog will appearand it will show the button and so on and so forth. This loop is working fine with me, but the issue I am having is that after the first dialog appears and I click on the button to hide the main window, the second time the main window appears, the button would appear as a "pressed" button, not as a new button. I think it's because I "pressed" on it the first time the main window appeared. And it stays like that until I stop the program and run it again.

So my question is, any idea how I can "reset" the button control? Or do I need to reset the mouse click event? Any pointers on this would be helpful.

Comment: An infinite loop inside a constructor is a very bad idea

Comment: @sir Rufo how come? can you please elaborate?

Comment: You cannot construct an instance from an infinite running constructor. The constructor returns an instance at the end, well it should but yours did not because there is an open end

Comment: The application lifecycle is roughly: 1. Create the MainWindow 2. Start the message loop for the application. Without that message loop your application will not work as expected. Your application will be at point 1 until termination.

Comment: @sir Rufo Okay. thank you for the pointer. So what is the best approach i can take if i want to make my app run continuously without stopping? That's what i am trying to achieve in the end.

Comment: Start a timer when the window is hiding (there is an event for that) which will show the window again. Thats all

Answer (score 1):

You should run the loop on a background thread. If you run it on the UI thread, the application won't be able to respond to user input.

The easiest and recommended way to run some code on a background thread is to start a new `Task`.

Also note that you cannot access the window from a background thread so you need to use the dispatcher to marshal the call back to the UI thread.

The following sample code should give you the idea.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => callmyfunction());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    public void callmyfunction()
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }

    private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```

Comment: *it should hide the main window and the window should sleep as per the milli-seconds I specified in thread.sleep and then it will wake up* has to be realized by a timer

Comment: What's your point? The sample code I posted minimizes the window when the button is clicked and then it is restored in the loop.

Comment: Good point. Yes, probably it should, since it is executing an infinite loop. I edited my answer.

Comment: My point: the window will be restored in 0 to 1000ms and not 1000ms after hiding. A simple timer would be enough